# find position of a point with origin, angle and radius

Tags: javascript, game-physics, trigonometry

im stuck with a trigonometry problem in a javascript game im trying to make.
with a origin point(xa,ya) a radius and destination point (ya,yb) I need to find the position of a new point.

```
//calculate a angle in degree
function angle(xa, ya, xb, yb) 
{
    var a= Math.atan2(yb - ya, xb - xa);
    a*= 180 / Math.PI;

    return a;
}


function FindNewPointPosition()
{
    //radius  origine(xa,xb)  destination(ya,yb)
    var radius=30;
    var a = angle(xa, xb, ya, yb);

    newpoint.x = xa + radius * Math.cos(a);
    newpoint.y = ya + radius * Math.sin(a);

    return newpoint;
}
```

Imagine a image because I dont have enough reputation to post one :
blue square is the map (5000x5000), black square (500x500) what players see (hud).
Cross(400,400) is the origin and sun(4200,4200) the destination.
The red dot (?,?) indicate to player which direction take to find the sun ..
But sun and cross position can be reverse or in different corner or anywhere !

At the moment the red dot do not do that at all ..

Tks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why did you use ATAN2? Change to Math.atan() - you will get angle in var A
2. Where you have to place your red dot? inside hud?

Corrected code
https://jsfiddle.net/ka9xr07j/embedded/result/

```
var obj = FindNewPointPosition(400,4200,400,4200); - new position 417. 425
```

Comment: 1. I dont know im very bad in Math, find example on this site .. with atan seems to be better .. but not allright                                                                 2. The cross stay in the middle of the hud as it move and red dot is around it.

Comment: Try this code https://jsfiddle.net/ka9xr07j/ - look to browser console. new.x and new.y are calculated correctly

Comment: I make somme modification https://jsfiddle.net/softindev/1qcbth3x/8/ but it display 430, 400 Why ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't saved latest updates in my jsFiddle. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/ka9xr07j/5/

Comment: use angle for what i want to do was a bad idea, could work with some condition

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find a solution without using angle.

```
function newpointposition(origin, destination)
{
    // radius distance between cross and red dot
    var r=30;

    // calculate a vector
    var xDistance = destination.x - origin.x;
    var yDistance = destination.y - origin.y;

    // normalize vector
    var length = Math.sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance);
    xDistance /= length;
    yDistance /= length;

    // add the radius
    xDistance = xDistance * r;
    yDistance = yDistance * r;

    var newpoint = { x: 0, y: 0 };

    newpoint.x = origin.x + xDistance;
    newpoint.y = origin.y + yDistance;

    return newpoint;

}

var radar = newpointposition({
     x: 500,
     y: 800
}, {
     x: 3600,
     y: 2850
});

alert(radar.x + ' ' + radar.y);
```

ty Trike, using jsfiddle really help me.